# Display a message box in Inno Setup after installation has finished?

Tags: inno-setup, messagebox

I am planning to allow my installer to install DirectX after the files installation has completed. How can I display a message box to prompt the user to install DirectX when the installation has finished?

Answer (score 4):

After each step `CurStepChanged` is called, you just need to check for the step post install to do what you want to do.

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin;
    if MsgBox('Do you want to install DirectX?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then
    begin
      // user clicked Yes
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: what should i do to add code in //user clicked Yes line?